# Detect collision between SKNode and Particles?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection, particle-system

I have this function that creates some lava:

```
func setupLava() {
    let emitter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Lava.sks")!
    emitter.particlePositionRange = CGVector(dx: 200, dy: 0.0)
    emitter.advanceSimulationTime(3.0)
    emitter.zPosition = 4
    emitter.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: 300)
    lava.addChild(emitter)

}
```

And I want to detect when the player collides with it. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Particles are not represented by objects in SpriteKit. This means you
>   cannot perform node-related tasks on particles, nor can you associate
>   physics bodies with particles to make them interact with other
>   content. Although there is no visible class representing particles
>   added by the emitter node, you can think of a particle as having
>   properties like any other object.

So you cannot use SpriteKit to detect collisions with the emitted Lava, but you can associate a physics body to the Lava object and collide with it not it individual emitted nodes. Use `categoryContactMask`, `contactBitMask` fields of the `physicsBody` of your nodes to detect contacts.